# Why is it that evolution of organisms had oxygen as their life-supporting gas?

Tags: evolution, biochemistry, macroevolution, origins

On Earth, gaseous N<sub>2</sub> is abundant. However, life began by dealing with O<sub>2</sub> and CO<sub>2</sub>.

What can be considered the major reason for life developing in such manner?

Comment: Ambient temperature range, oxygen & water at the same time?

Comment: Have you ever tried to do chemistry with gaseous nitrogen?

Comment: Life did NOT begin with “dealing” with oxygen. It was anaerobic before the great oxygenation. And if you expressed a chemical question in chemical terms instead of using words like “dealing with” you would be nearer to considering for yourself the chemistry and thermodynamics involved.

Answer (score 3):

$\ce{N2}$ may be abundant, but in the environmental conditions typical of Earth today, and back when life appeared, [$\ce{N2}$ is nearly inert](http://www.uigi.com/nitrogen.html). That is, $\ce{N2}$ generally doesn't participate in chemical reactions except at higher temperatures or with special catalysts. $\ce{O2}$ on the other hand can participate in many chemical reactions at temperatures and pressures typical for Earth. At a more fundamental level, the reason for the inertness of $\ce{N2}$ is that the [electron affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity_(data_page)) of $\mathrm{N}$ is much less than the electron affinity of $\mathrm{O}$.

Think of it this way: Q: why don't we build cars out of tissue paper? A: Because the material properties of tissue paper are a poor match to the material requirements of cars.

Comment: Why not use `$\ce{O2}$`? It's used widely at Chemistry SE.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question to fix that.

Comment: I was just wondering whether there is a particular reason to use `\mathrm` instead of `\ce` if both are supported.

Comment: \mathrm is a generic tag for turning off italicization  of symbols. \ce is a tag specifically created for annotating chemical formula, so the choice of tag helps convey the semantics of the the formatting.

Comment: Amusingly, I did not even know that `\ce` worked outside Chemistry SE until 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo: And those of us who don't regularly do chemistry wouldn't even know that :-)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo   Better to use HTML <sub> tag as it doesn’t change the typeface. Especially as the question shows no consideration of chemical energetics. Why waste time with it anyway?

Comment: @David, you seem to have a rather idiosyncratic model of posting style. I've had my posts edited on other exchanges for **not** using the appropriate MathJax for chemical symbols. As far as I know there is no preferred style guide for this exchange, so users are free to use MathJax or not as their personal preference dictates.

Comment: The method used to achieve a certain typographic effect should be unimportant if the result is the same with different techniques.  In the case of subscripts and superscripts the methods available yield *different* results — HTML maintains the sans serif typeface and size, MathJax results in serif typeface that is different in size. My recommendation is not “personal preference” but standard biochemical usage as found in e.g. J. Biol. Chem. and Biochem. J. The rationale is that there is no need to make such expressions stand out from the text — they are *not* mathematical displays.